# How to combine two event handlers into one in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to combine these two jQuery functions into one, thereby removing the unnecessary duplication?

```
$('form#search input').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('a#clear').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('a#clear').show();
  } 
});

$('form#search select').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('a#clear').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('a#clear').show();
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to bind these conditionally in the most elegant, shortest way possible you can do this:

```
var $formSearch = $('form#search'),
    hideShow = function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          $('a#clear').hide();
        }
        else {
          $('a#clear').show();
        }
    };

$formSearch.find('input').on('keyup', hideShow); 
$formSearch.find('select').on('change', hideShow);
```

If you want both event to be triggered for both selectors, you can do this. It might be okay to do this, since you might want these to be triggered anyways.

```
$('form#search input, form#search select').on('keyup change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('a#clear').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('a#clear').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I am using `$('form#search input, form#search select')` to target both fields, though.

Comment: If you look carefully the selectors are slightly different in OPs example.

Comment: Fixed. You can use multiple selectors separated by a comma.

Comment: Well, I guess the problem with this is that it triggers both events for each selector...

Comment: New edit shows a couple of options depending on what approach you want to take.

Comment: How to pass event parameter in order to make preventDefault()  when calling functions like that?

Answer (score 6):

Define one function to handle the event and then assign it as follows:

```
function inputChanged() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('a#clear').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('a#clear').show();
    }
}

$('form#search input').on('keyup', inputChanged);
$('form#search select').on('change', inputChanged);
```

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494137/227299) may be more helpful to the OP, but this is clearer in answering the question. Want the same thing to happen from two places? Make it a function

Comment: How to pass event parameter in order to make preventDefault() when calling functions like that?